# Сравнительный союз "как" и устойчивое/неустойчивое выражение

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология, сравнительный-оборот, обороты-с-как, устойчивое

У меня каждый раз сердце обливалось кровью, так близко щёлкали его зубы. Они были **острыми как бритвы** – непонятно, зачем он держал на столе этот обрезатель сигар в виде Моники Левински.

Виктор Пелевин, "Священная книга оборотня"

Можно ли считать отсутствие запятых в этом случае показателем того, что этот автор, в отличие от авторов других предложений с этим оборотом, посчитал это выражение устойчивым?

Comment: Тема интересная, голос от меня. Всегда ли фразеологизмы обязаны не обособляться или это наше неточное понимание темы в принципе?  Какая связь между устойчивостью и обособлением?  Мне тоже хотелось бы послушать ответы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
      Розенталь § 42 Сравнительный оборот (пункт 2)

   Вопрос о пунктуации при сравнительных оборотах, в 
   частности при сравнениях идиоматического 
   (фразеологического) характера, не может решаться в отрыве 
   от характера самих оборотов (сравнения общеязыкового типа 
   или художественные сравнения, иногда индивидуально- 
   авторские), состава устойчивых сочетаний, как он 
   представлен в толковых и фразеологических словарях 
   русского языка, и т. д.
```

1. Вряд ли можно считать, что автор **сверялся со справочником** Розенталя, где указан перечень наиболее распространенных устойчивых сочетаний с союзом КАК. В то же время можно услышать такое мнение: не обособляется, **потому что фразеологизм.**

Обособление сравнительных оборотов — непростая тема. Художественные сравнения **чаще обособляются**. Реже подчеркивается **обстоятельственное** значение для оборота, и тогда нет обособления. Но какие особенности можно увидеть **во фразеологическом обороте?**

Такой оборот имеет значение **одного слова** (обычно наречия): *острый **как бритва*** — это ***очень** острый*. Но в отличие от наречия у оборота **сложный состав**, и ему труднее вписаться в структуру предложения.

2. **Нормальная** позиция **обстоятельства** по отношению к сказуемому — это **постпозиция** . Например: *бежать (как?) бЫстро.*  В этом случае **ударение** делается только на обстоятельстве, а сказуемое находится **в безударной** позиции. Поэтому смотрим **на структуру** предложения:

*Они были **острыми как брИтвы** – // непонятно, зачем он держал на столе этот обрезатель сигар в виде Моники Левински.*

Это **БСП,** отношения **взаимообусловленные** и обозначены тире. Оборот находится **в ударной позиции**, именно поэтому он **не обособляется** (на сказуемом ударения нет).

3. Но точно ли это так? **Для проверки** изменим предложение и используем союзную связь:

*Они были **Острыми, как брИтвы,** так что непонятно, зачем он держал на столе этот обрезатель сигар в виде Моники Левински.*

Здесь оборот **обособляется** и делается **два ударения** — на сказуемом и на обороте.

4. **В Нацкорпусе** можно встретить **оба варианта:**

*Независимость поведения и **Острый, как бритва,** язык никогда не способствовали быстрой карьере талантливого дипломата...*

*За поясом у него топор. **Острый, как брИтва**. Любит он свой топор.*

*Жара, озноб; **острый как бритва свЕт** и скрежет чужой речи...*

*— Веревка отрезана ножом, — крикнул он, — и хорошо отрезана! Нож был **острый как брИтва.***

Comment: Хороший ответ, плюс от меня.

Comment: @Sharon Поясните, пожалуйста, п.3 своего ответа. Написано не обособляется, а стоят запятые.

Comment: Спасибо, я исправила.

Comment: @Sharon Как всегда, замечательное объяснение вопроса, но позвольте обратить ваше внимание на то, что среднестатистическому носителю языка бывает трудно запомнить ударение в слове "звонит", а вы предлагаете ему вслушиваться в ударение целой группы слов и пытаться уловить мелодию языка, прежде чем решить поставить запятую или нет. Для рядового пользователя это не то что сложно, это архисложно. Этот факт доказывает большая вариативность постановки запятых разными авторами при другом сравнительном устойчивом обороте, например, "как зеницу ока". Хотя, конечно, учиться, учиться и учиться, товарищи.

Comment: @Sharon Поэтому, я думаю, назрела необходимость хотя бы некоего алгоритма действий при решении такой пунктуационной задачи.

Comment: «Алгоритм в информатике — это понятный исполнителю набор правил для решения конкретного множества задач, который получает входные данные и возвращает результат за конечное время».  Но ведь в ПАС и у Розенталя предлагаются алгоритмы, и вы можете использовать справочники. Все так и делают.  Мне тоже хотелось услышать ответ без интонационного анализа, но никто не стал отвечать. Ну вот алгоритм: если вы увидите оборот перед тире  в БСП, то его не надо обособлять. Такой подойдет?

Comment: К тому же вы спрашиваете про автора. который "посчитал это выражение устойчивым".  Да никак он не считал, мастера слова пишут по интуиции, они "чувствуют"  правильную речь. Так художник выбирает нужную краску.  Можно ли этому научиться?  Я считаю,  что понять основы  построения художественного текста вполне возможно .  И я использую все три принципа при решении задач: семантика  + грамматика + интонация.  Да и разговорная речь!  Там уж точно никакие алгоритмы не помогут.   А коммуникативность! О ней раньше вообще не говорили.

Comment: Я за свободу – пусть каждый выбирает по себе.  Как сказал Р. Шекли, в супчике должно быть все:  и оранжевая морковка, и  жемчужная луковичка. Здесь у нас площадка, где каждый может предложить свой метод.  Было бы интересно увидеть решение этой задачи с помощью алгоритмов. Попробуйте! Возможно, это будет интересно.

Comment: @Sharon Как минимум, для себя я сделал вывод: прежде чем рука потянется поставить запятую при сравнительном союзе как, надо в первую очередь подумать, не является ли он предикативной связкой, и проверить сравнительный оборот по базе ФЕ. Это как шаг первый.)

Comment: У меня воспитание строго грамматическое, никаких вольностей в этом плане))  Разве оборот может быть предикативной связкой? Какой вид сказуемого, СГС или СИС? Вероятно, вы имеете в виду тесную связь обстоятельства-оборота  со сказуемым. И как же вы это проверите? В этом и есть смысл решения, а вы меняете Х на У))  Кроме того, у меня появилась идея: предложение можно иначе оформить. Потом расскажу.

Comment: Я имею в виду, например: у неё глаза как озёра. Не сам оборот, а союз как.

Comment: У нас сказуемое зубы были острыми, а оборот обозначает степень признака (насколько острыми). Поэтому его можно обособить или нет.  А дальше как? У фраз. оборота по части обособления нет особых преимуществ по сравнению с обычными оборотами. У них только семантика особая. Или вы думаете, что им нужны свои правила?

Answer (score 1):

**Интонационная загадка**

Сравним два варианта:

(1) **Авторский вариант**

*Они были **острыми как брИтвы – непонятно,** зачем он держал на столе / этот обрезатель сигар / в виде Моники Левински.*

(2) **Возможный вариант**

*Они были **Острыми, как брИтвы, – непонятно**, зачем он **вообще** держал на столе / этот обрезатель сигар / в виде Моники Левински.*

Насколько **корректны** эти решения? Они **различаются на слух**? Насколько обоснованным представляется **единый знак?**

Почему загадка? Мне хочется показать, насколько **важна интонация** при выборе знаков препинания.

**Примечание**. Наречие ***вообще*** добавлено для большей распространенности второй части.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ ОТ 10.11.2023 г.**

Расскажу об интонации (может, кому интересно).

**Авторский вариант:**

*Они были **острыми** **как брИтвы** – непонятно, зачем он держал на столе этот обрезатель сигар в виде Моники Левински.*

Итак, автор выбрал **тире**, а оборот **не обособил**. А какое это тире. Тире бывает **двух видов**: **разделительное** с повышением голоса перед паузой и **присоединительное** с понижением голоса.

Здесь **присоединительное** тире: пауза обозначена, но **не так велика.** Мы достаточно **быстро** переходим от факта к суждению о нем, и **необособленный** оборот позволяет это сделать.

А если его **обособить**? Ведь в принципе такой вариант вполне **возможен**. Но тогда быстрого перехода **не получится** – придется сделать ударение **на прилагательном**. Соответственно **основная** пауза будет **больше**, и ее придется обозначить **не тире, а единым знаком.**

К тому же **дополнительная** запятая также может быть обоснованием для постановки единого знака:

*Они были **Острыми, как брИтвы,** – непонятно, зачем он держал на столе этот обрезатель сигар в виде Моники Левински.*

**Примечание.** А если вторую часть дополнительно **распространить**, то и оснований для постановки единого знака будет больше.